# Complement of compact subset of the plane is simply-connected

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

<s>Let $K$ be a non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ .</s>

Is $U = \mathbb{R}^2 / K$ ever simply-connected?

Perhaps [Alexander duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality) is relevant, but the relevant cohomology is a bit tricky to compute if $K$ is not locally contractible.

Unfortunately, some mental error has occurred between recall of the hypothesis of the statement and transcription of the question. **$K$ is in fact not compact, but instead can be generated by finite unions and arbitrary intersection of sets of the form $A\times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\times B$, with $A,B$ compact.** Apologies.

Comment: Regardless of the downvotes and the requests to close, I believe this is a good question from the point of view of a mathematician.

Comment: Pick a circle that contains the compact set in its interior. Can you contract that circle continuously to a single point?

Comment: I'd start with $K=\{x_0\}$. If you cannot continuously deform the circle in this case, you also cannot do it for any other non-empty compact set.

Comment: If you remove anything like $A\times \mathbb{R}$, your resulting space is no longer path-connected and thus not simply connected.

Comment: @Severin Yes, I realized. My confusion stemmed from the false belief that quotient maps are open.

Comment: @Thomas: The title says "complement", the body of the question says "quotient" (also, "Alexander duality" suggests "complement", comments by OP again suggest "quotient"): To me, what's written is not even a question, let alone a good one.